# Is it possible to attain Blur effect and motion Blur effect in IE8 and other major browsers without using html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add normal blur as well as motion blur effect in my project. As we are using Html 4.01, Is there any solution which would add blur effect without using Html 5? Tried with Css filter, But it wont support firefox and IE. Possibly a simple plugin which would solve cross browser issue as well?

Comment: `Blur` in relation to `HTML` is a `DOM` event. It occurs when an element loses focus, for example when a user types their name into a form field and then click outside that field. Bluring and 'motion blur' sound like animations related to javascript. They are not industry terms, you will have to define them for us. Also, posting what you have already tried (your code) goes a long way towards getting better answers.

Comment: is IE8 still alive? Majority of the modern frameworks don't provide IE8 support.

Comment: Have a look at vague.js https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js/

Comment: Use images. It will require a bit planning though.

Comment: @jefffabiny: Well i just tried with css3 blur effect. By the time i finished it i realized including older versions of firefox and Ie wont support which is still in demand  browser.

Comment: @Mathias: Yes I will have a look on it, I will update. Thanks.

Comment: @Epistemex: Yes, That is the solution we thought about if we dont find any better alternative that would support IE8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/CD3qv/479/)**</kbd> helps you

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <!--[if lt IE 9 ]>

        <body class="oldie">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 9 ]>

            <body class="ie9">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]>
                <!-->

                <body class="modern">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div id="plane">
                    <header><span id="etbr">reflection<span id="refl">reflection</span></span>
                    </header>
                </div>
                </body>

</html>
```

css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
#plane {
    padding-top: 5%;
    left: 0;
    top: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 1080px;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
}
#etbr, #refl {
    color: #F0F;
    font-family: Impact, 'Arial Black', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 200px;
    background-color: #FFE;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 240, .2) 0 0 200px 100px, rgba(255, 255, 240, .3) 0 0 40px, inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 0 0 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#refl {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    /*filter: url(filter.svg#blur); /* FF, Opera + IE10*/
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    /* webkit */
    box-shadow: inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 0 0 20px, inset #000 0 50px 100px;
}
.modern #refl {
    opacity: .25;
}
.ie9 #refl {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(opacity=.25) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3', MakeShadow='false') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=15, direction=0) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3', MakeShadow='false');"
}
.oldie #refl {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#00000000) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(mirror=1, rotation=2, opacity=.35) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3', MakeShadow='false') progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=15, direction=0) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3', MakeShadow='false');
}
```

[source](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-reflections-glows-and-blurs--webdesign-6294)

Comment: Are you sure this will work in IE8? Seems like you are using a lot of "HTML5" (CSS3) features that is not supported.

Comment: I am not sure, you can give it a try.. sorry for not providing a full proof answer.

Comment: @Gaurav: Thanks for response. But thats not what i was looking for. My project is clearly not a Html5 Site. I have to support even IE8

Answer (score 0):

Dint find a proper solution. So will be going for SVG for now. Even Svg is not supported in all browsers. But its supported in most of the browsers.
I even came across EaslJs http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS. Pretty good !!